# How to create a session in salesforce

Tags: session

How to create or set a session in sales force.I am not using site.login for logging.I am manually checking username and password(Custom Field) and once checked.I have to create a session when navigating to another page

Answer (score 2):

ONE OPTION -

First of all, create a Custom Label 'Login_Request' with value as-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><urn:organizationId>@@@@OrgId@@@@</urn:organizationId></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:login><urn:username>@@@@Username@@@@</urn:username><urn:password>@@@@Password@@@@</urn:password></urn:login></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Next inside apex class Create the below method to login into system and get Session ID -

```
public string GetOrgAccessToken() {
        string sessionId;
        string orgId = **18DIGIT_ORG_ID**;
        string suborgId=orgId.substring(0,15);
        string orgbody=Label.Login_Request.replace('@@@@OrgId@@@@',suborgId);
        string userbody=orgbody.replace('@@@@Username@@@@',pHeader.**USERNAME**);
        string Pwdbody=userbody.replace('@@@@Password@@@@',pHeader.**PASSWORD**);
        string body = Pwdbody;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://LOGIN_OR_TEST.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        req.setTimeOut(30000);
        req.setBody(body);
        Http p = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = p.send(req);
        loginResponse = res.getbody();
        Xmlstreamreader reader = new Xmlstreamreader(res.getbody());
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.Characters) {
                if (string.valueof(reader.getText()).startswith(suborgId + '!')) {
                    sessionId = reader.getText();
                }
                if(string.valueof(reader.getText()).startswith('https://')){
                    getTicketsEndpoint = reader.getText();
                }
            }
            reader.next();
        }
        return sessionId;
    }
```

Pay special attention and replace the bold text. Important parameters are **18 Digit org ID, Username, Password, Endpoint**. Ensure that endpoint base URL is login.salesforce.com for Production or DEV org and test.salesforce.com for Sandboxes.